# ActiveModel serializers json api format deserializition

Tags: ruby, activerecord, active-model-serializers, json-api

i'm using AMS version 0.10.0.rc2. it support json api format. it's ok. but i wanna deserialize request data (json api formatted) to activerecord model. any idea?

Answer (score 2):

I don't think it supports deserialization of JSON-API just yet. It shouldn't be long though, see thread here: https://github.com/rails-api/active_model_serializers/pull/950